# Is there any notification to get before application did enter background?

Tags: iphone, ios

Im developing an iPhone App, need to do something before application did enter background, I know there are applicationWillEnterForeground and applicationDidEnterBackground

But can't find a application**Will**EnterBackground notification, anyone know how to do that?

Comment: When your `applicationDidEnterBackground ` you have approximately 5 seconds to finish up whatever you need to do. Short of contacting a server and waiting for some data to transfer, this should be enough time for most things to finish. What is it that you need to do?

Answer (score 24):

Register for this notification in viewDidLoad or at init:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
```

In Swift 5.0

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillResignActive(notification:)), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

@objc func applicationWillResignActive(notification: NSNotification) {
   //do a thing
}
```

In Swift 4.0

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillResignActive(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)

@objc func applicationWillResignActive(notification: NSNotification) {
   //do a thing
}
```

Comment: 'appWillResignActive' would be your own method that does something in response to the notification.

Answer (score 1):

applicationWillResignActive:

Tells the delegate that the application is about to become inactive.

Comment: An incoming call also post applicationWillResignActive, it's not a notification for app entering to background

Comment: If you get an incoming call the application will enter background and you will get the callback I just posted.

Comment: This is not correct, your app will resign active if you get an UIAlertView from the system, even though your app is visible through it. If you dismiss the alert you go straight back to your app without having been in the background at all.